# Correlating very few discrete numbers - is it ok? How to visualize?

Tags: correlation, data-visualization

I have measurements of 700 instances, which get a value between -3 and 3 (-3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3).  I have these measurements for 8 different experiments.  I get the expected correlations, but because the data can only be in these discrete numbers, I am unable to plot experiment #1 vs experiment #2 as a dot plot (as all points fall on other points).

This made me worry whether correlating such discrete values is legitimate to do?  In addition, is there a way to visualize the correlations, or some spread of the points and not just the correlation coefficient?

Comment: You're asking two quite different questions which might be better asked separately; the one about displaying discrete data has been addressed on site a few times before (jittering is a common choice, though there are several other options).

Comment: Agreed.  But in some ways I think you are over-thinking this.  The dots may overlap, but what matters here is the histogram of the umber of dots per value.  You can show the actual histograms.  Statistical interpretation will require ANOVA or some such.

Comment: the number of points per value is not enough. I am more interested to show that if one instance had +2 value in one experiment, it also had it in the other experiment. When I do jitter to the 2 vectors, I get the dots around the values but still it is difficult the very high correlation coefficient that I get.

Comment: With seven categories a tabular presentation might be best.